# Google Maps load sidebar by marker category

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This is kind of an update to a question I asked earlier but never got an answer here [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223751/google-maps-load-multiple-sidebars-by-marker-category). I've got a google map that creates and loads different categories of markers from an xml file when the corresponding checkbox is clicked and then updates the list on a sidebar. I'd like to load each category into its own separate sidebar so I can split them up or stack them side-by-side, etc. When I click the check-boxes the first list (the list of huts) gets loaded into both sidebars but the second list (list of yurts) gets loaded correctly into its corresponding sidebar. I don't understand why one list gets loaded into both sidebars but the other list gets loaded correctly into just one. Thanks in advance for any help. The code is all below:

Javascript

```
      var side_bar_html = ""; 

      //var for kml route layers
      var routes = {
     y: {
        name: "Winter Routes",
        url: "http://www.huts.org/Tests/Maps/GPSTracks/Margys_MacV2.kml"

    },
    z: {
        name: "Summer Routes",
        url: "http://www.huts.org/Tests/Maps/GPSTracks/Telluride_to_Last_Dollar.kml"

    },

};

      var gmarkers = [];
      var gicons = [];
      var map = null;


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(100,150)
  });


gicons["ltblue"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/marker2_ltblue.png");

  var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/marker2_ltblue.png');



function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
   if ((typeof(iconColor)=="undefined") || (iconColor==null)) { 
      iconColor = "ltblue"; 
   }
   if (!gicons[iconColor]) {
      gicons[iconColor] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/marker2_"+ iconColor +".png");
   } 
   return gicons[iconColor];

}

function category2color(category) {
   var color = "ltblue";
   switch(category) {
     case "huts": color = "ltblue";
                break;
     case "yurts":    color = "orange";
                break;
    case "demohuts":    color = "red";
                break;
     default:   color = "ltblue";
                break;
   }
   return color;
}

      gicons["huts"] = getMarkerImage(category2color("huts"));
      gicons["yurts"] = getMarkerImage(category2color("yurts"));
      gicons["demohuts"] = getMarkerImage(category2color("demohuts"));


      // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
function createMarker(latlng,name,html,category) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: gicons[category],

        map: map,
        title: name,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
        marker.mycategory = category;                                 
        marker.myname = name;
        gmarkers.push(marker);

  //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      // infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
      // infowindow.open(map,marker);
      // });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     var testimonial = document.getElementById('hutMapinfo');
        testimonial.innerHTML = contentString;
       });

}


      // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
      function show(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
          }
        }
        // == check the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
      }

      // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
      function hide(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
        // == clear the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
        // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
        infowindow.close();
      }

      // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
      function boxclick(box,category) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(category);
        } else {
          hide(category);
        }
        // == rebuild the side bar
        makeSidebar();
      }

      function myclick(i) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
      } 

      // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
      function makeSidebar() {
        var html = "";
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
            html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')" onmouseover="gmarkers['+ i +'].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)" onmouseout="gmarkers['+ i +'].setAnimation(null)">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
          }
          document.getElementById(gmarkers[i].mycategory+"side_bar").innerHTML = html;
        }

      }

  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.192948, -105.089823),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);



    //google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
       // infowindow.close();
       // });



      // Read the data
      downloadUrl("coloradoYurtsToggleTest.xml", function(doc) {
  var xml = xmlParse(doc);
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
          var html = GXml.value(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("infowindow")[0]);
          var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
          var season = markers[i].getAttribute("season");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
        }

        // == show or hide the categories initially ==
        show("huts");

        hide("yurts");

        // == create the initial sidebar ==
        makeSidebar();
      });
      createRouteTogglers();
    }


// the important function... routes[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
function toggleRoute(checked, id) {

    if (checked) {

        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(routes[id].url, {
            preserveViewport: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: false 
        });
        // store kml as obj
        routes[id].obj = layer;
        routes[id].obj.setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        routes[id].obj.setMap(null);
        delete routes[id].obj;
    }

};

// create the Routes controls
function createRouteTogglers() {

    var html = "<form><ul>";
    for (var prop in routes) {
        html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
        " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleRoute(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
        routes[prop].name + "<\/li>";
    }
    html += "<\/ul><\/form>";

    document.getElementById("routeLayers").innerHTML = html;
};

// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
    var selected = 'selected';
    var normal = 'normal';
    document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected: normal);
};
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>10th Mountain Division Hut Association</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 

    <title>Google Maps Javascript API v3 Example: Marker Categories</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/10thMtn2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="GXml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xmlToggle2.js"></script>
    <title>Google Maps</title>


  </head>
<body onload="initialize()"> 

<?php include('includes/header3.php'); ?>


<div id="map_canvas" style="width:65%; height:625px;"></div>
<div id="toggle_box">


    <div id="routeLayers"></div>
    <form action="#">
      <img src="images/marker2_ltblue.png"> Huts: <input type="checkbox" id="hutsbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'huts')" />
      <img src="images/marker2_orange.png"> Yurts: <input type="checkbox" id="yurtsbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'yurts')" />
      </form>
    <div id="hutsside_bar">
    </div>
    <div id="yurtsside_bar">
    </div>



</div>

<div id="hutMapinfo"></div>


<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>

    <noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
      However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
      To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
      try again.
    </noscript>

  </body>

</html>
```

xml snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<markers>
<marker lat="39.369804" lng="-106.388725" label="10th Mountain Division Hut" category="huts" season="winter">
 <infowindow>
<![CDATA[
    <div class="info">
    <button class="tiny radius" id="closer">X</button>
    <h5>10th Mountain Division Hut</h5>
    <div class="hutMapTitle">
    <img src="http://www.huts.org/images/10thMtn/10thMountainsmall.jpg"/>
    <h6>10th Mountain Hut System</h6>
    <h6>(970)925-5775</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="hutMapList">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.huts.org/The_Huts/10th_mountain.html" target="_blank">10th Mtn Division Huts Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.huts.org" target="_blank">Book This Hut</a></li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Seasons:</span> Winter &amp Summer</li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Price:</span> $33 per person</li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Capacity:</span> 16 people</li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Distance:</span> 4.4 miles</li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Elevation Gain:</span> 1200ft
    </ul>   
    </div>
    <p>Nestled at timberline below the majestic peaks of the Colorado Continental Divide, 10th Mountain Division Hut forms a perfect destination for a single hut trip or ski-through using other nearby huts. In summer, dozens of hiking and cycling routes start or end just outside the door.</p></div>]]></infowindow>
    </marker>
<marker lat="37.059971" lng="-106.480865" label="Trujillo Meadows Yurt" category="yurts">
 <infowindow>
  <![CDATA[
    <div class="info">
    <button class="tiny radius" id="closer">X</button>
    <h5>Trujillo Meadows Yurt</h5>
    <div class="hutMapTitle">
    <img src="http://www.huts.org/images/GMaps/trujilloMeadowsYurt.jpg"/>
    <h6>Southwest Nordic Center</h6>
    <h6>(575)758-4761</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="hutMapList">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.southwestnordiccenter.com/yurtdescriptions.htm#TMyurt" target="_blank">Southwest Nordic Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.southwestnordiccenter.com/reservationsandratesIII.htm" target="_blank">Book This Hut</a></li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Seasons:</span> Winter &amp Summer</li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Price:</span> $125 per night</li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Capacity:</span> 10 people</li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Distance:</span> 4.1 miles</li>
        <li><span class="subheading">Elevation Gain:</span> 380ft</li>
    </ul>   
    </div>
    <p>Located north Cumbres Pass in south central Colorado, the Trujillo Meadows Yurt is gentle open slopes out the front door of the yurt perfect for beginning and intermediate telemarkers. Advanced skiers will have fun looking for shots on the extensive north facing tree slopes. A full day loop is possible up to the Flat Mtn. ridge and back via the Los Pinos Creek.</p></div>]]></infowindow>
    </marker>
</markers>
```

Comment: What does your xml look like?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem? It doesn't look like your actual question has anything to do with the title of this question.  Where was your previous question?  That might help provide some context.

Comment: I edited my original post to add a link to the previous question and an xml sample. The title is probably confusing as I wasn't sure how to describe the problem. As it is now when I click the "huts" checkbox the list of huts is loaded into the "hutsside_bar" and the "yurtsside_bar" while when I check the "yurts" checkbox its loads the yurts list into just the "yurtsside_bar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makeSidebar function has an issue (it is doing what you coded it to do, which is the behavior you are seeing):

```
function makeSidebar() {
  var html = "";
  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
      html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')" onmouseover="gmarkers['+ i +'].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)" onmouseout="gmarkers['+ i +'].setAnimation(null)">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById(gmarkers[i].mycategory+"side_bar").innerHTML = html;
  }
}
```

If you want unique text for each "sidebar", you should make a unique version of "html" for each sidebar.  Something like this:

```
var html = null;
function makeSidebar() {
  // empty any pre-existing sidebar entries
  for (i in html) {
    document.getElementById(i+"side_bar").innerHTML = "";
  }
  html = []; // make html an array
  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
      // make entry for category if it doesn't already exist
      if (!html[gmarkers[i].mycategory])
         html[gmarkers[i].mycategory] = "";
      // add the entry to the sidebar specific to the category
      html[gmarkers[i].mycategory] += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')" onmouseover="gmarkers['+ i +'].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)" onmouseout="gmarkers['+ i +'].setAnimation(null)">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
     }
   }
   for (i in html) {
      document.getElementById(i+"side_bar").innerHTML = html[i];
   }
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cae2/3/)

Comment: Thanks so much, that should work. Just need to switch a few things so it empties the sidebars when the box is unchecked and I should be set. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks again, this has been a huge help.